# How to add length 1 dimension to NDArray en c#

Tags: c#, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an NDArray of shape (480, 640, 3) in c# using NumSharp.

I need to reshape it to (1, 480, 640, 3).

On python it would be with `imgArr = imgArr.reshape((1, 480, 640, 3))`.

How can this be done on c#?

Thank you!

*PS: Sorry for the tags, but there are not NumSharp nor NumSharp-NDArray tags and I can't add tags yet.*

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a bit ok luck. I can't explain why, but the solution was to give a -1 in one of the three lasts dimensions,  `imgArr = imgArr.reshape(new Shape(1, 480, -1, 3))`.

(for the curious,   `imgArr = imgArr.reshape(new Shape(1, 480, 640, 3))` did not work)